# My website crashes when I click a certain link twice

Tags: html, web, href

I am trying to develop a navigation bar for a website with a dropdown menu. I am running it locally and have the "links" stored in a folder called categories
This line of HTML is giving me issues

```
<li><a href="./categories/about.shtml">About</a></li>
```

The first time when I go to the about page it works fine, but I run into a bug in that if I click the "About" dropdown again there is an error because it is searching for "categories/categories/about.shtml.

Is there any way for me to use href so that it will essentially search a file tree from a given "root" to prevent this from happening.

Comment: The reason is you're using relative path. You would need to use absolute path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a relative path, when on the home page you do click the link the path of the link is not the same.

At home page is:

```
<li><a href="./categories/about.shtml">About</a></li>
```

But when you click it, and you navigate to it, it should become to:

```
<li><a href="./about.shtml">About</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many [types of URL Paths](http://www.dirigodev.com/blog/seo-web-best-practices/relative-vs-absolute-urls-seo/).

Use a "Root relative path

```
<li><a href="/categories/about.shtml">About</a></li>
```

This will always map to : `http://yoursite.com/categories/about.shtml`